# Strange Menu Bar

Tags: unity, icons, appearance, menu-bar

More often than not, when I boot into Ubuntu, the menu bars are completely white and non-transparent. Many of the icons are different too. All my folders and jar files are also just white sheets of paper. Is there any way to fix this from happening?
[image: The strange menu bar and the changed icons]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have selected the **Radiance** theme:

*click screenshot to enlarge*

[image: radiance theme]

Try going to **System Settings** -> **Appearance** -> **Look** -> **Theme** and changing it to Ambiance (the default theme).

Comment: It was already on ambiance. And sometimes it does boot up correctly, but it sometimes does this instead.